# Getting error while enter text in textfield like: _NSLayoutTreeLineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

Application crash when enter text in uitextfiled and getting error like: _NSLayoutTreeLineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index 7.
Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: <UITextFieldDelegate> write in .h file ???????

Comment: I also try <UITextFieldDelegate> write in .h, but still getting same error. some times getting error like NSRangeException', [NSBigMutableString getCharacters:range:]: Range....

Answer (score 1):

The `__NSLayoutTreeLineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index` stuff does (to the best of my knowledge) not cause the crash.

But there seems to be an underlying cause for both the crash and the invalid glyph. These kinds of errors pop up in places like custom `NSTextStorage` subclasses's `-processEditing`, when your perform changes to the text storage while layout is in progress and/or vice versa.

### How to Find Bugs in General & in TextKit Components Specifically

Since the OP didn't offer more details, here's a suggested list to *find* instead of *solving* the problem. After every step, try to run the program and look for crashes:

1. Remove any TextKit related custom subclasses and delegates (!) from the component, including `UITextField` subclasses themselves, and use system default components instead. This should not crash anymore.
2. Try to put the delegates back into place, if there were any. I'm thinking about `NSTextStorageDelegate` and friends.
3. If nothing crashes, deactivate the delegates again. (If it does, you know whose fault it is now :))

Now on to component subclasses; put the subclasses back into operation in this order, derived from the chain of responsibility in the layout process, one by one:

1. Add back custom `NSGlyphGenerator` subclasses, if any. They are way down the command chain. If nothing happens, use the system default again for now.
2. Do the same for `NSTypesetter` subclasses, put it in, then toggle it off again.
3. Same for `NSLayoutManager` subclasses, if any. This stuff is still further down the command chain.
4. Add back custom `NSTextStorage` subclass. Text storages are high up the command chain and may have multiple places where they can break.

Then try combinations, starting at the bottom again, and try as many combos as you need until the app breaks.

Once you find the exact call that causes the crash, open a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Had a pretty similar issue with dictation + multiline input TextEditor on SwiftUI iOS 14, iPhone XS.
No working solution was discovered so switched back to single line.
I liked ctietze suggestion on a dynamic layout - I think it was the case for a multiline textInput that forced reload of UI and resign first responder.

```
[Assert] View <(null):0x0> does not conform to UITextInput protocol
[KBDAnalyticsLog] -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.
!!! _NSLayoutTreeGetBaselineOffsetForGlyphAtIndex invalid glyph index 0
```

Code:

```
TextFieldSection(
  title: "title here",
  placeholder: "placeholder",
  text: self.$text,
  isSingleLine: false
)

struct TextFieldSection: View {
...
var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text(title)
            {
            //Would better keep ios 13 - text field, ios 14 - multiline edit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor
            if isSingleLine {
                TextField(placeholder, text: text)
            } else {
                if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                    TextEditor(text: text)
                } else {
                    TextField(placeholder, text: text)
                }
            }
```

The trick is control worked for other parts of the app and faulted only on modal screen with user dictation.

PS disabled any 3d party keyboard to avoid warning - didn't help as well.